# Output unique categories of entries

Tags: channel-entries, categories

I have a page where I'm outputting news entries. And these all are assigned to categories. And based on these, I have a jQuery plugin that sorts the entries visible based on the categories.

So my markup basically looks like this:

```
<ul id="news_categories">
    <li><a class="filter" data-filter="mix-all">All</a></li>
    {exp:channel:entries channel="News" dynamic="no" show_empty="no"}
        {categories}
            <li><a class="filter" data-filter="{category_name}">{category_name}</a></li>
        {/categories}
    {/exp:channel:entries}
</ul>
```

Now, this outputs the categories, but I only want unique ones. Right now, this outputs the following:

- All
- Photo
- Courses
- Arrangements
- Photo
- School
- Arrangements
- School

You probably get the idea. How can I output only unique categories?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be using the `{exp:channel:categories}` tag instead since you're only grabbing the category names. [View the user guide](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/categories.html).

```
<ul id="news_categories">
    <li><a class="filter" data-filter="mix-all">All</a></li>
    {exp:channel:categories channel="News" show_empty="no" style="linear"}
        <li><a class="filter" data-filter="{category_name}">{category_name}</a></li>
    {/exp:channel:categories}
</ul>
```

Comment: Of course! Thank you :) Expression Engine is so flexible, sometimes I forget the most obvious answer